# How to genarate JWT token using both environment variable's and user model

Tags: laravel, jwt

1. jwt token works perfectly with user model.
2. jwt tokens works perfectly with environment variable's.
3. Using both scenario 1 and 2 in one system.
   I want to generate jwt token using environment variable's email and password which are not stored in user table and also I don't want to change the existing flow of jwt token.

I want to generate JWT token for master user who is not part of system and his email and password are not stored in database.

Is there any way to generate jwt token using both user model and environment variable's??

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Add a minimal code example for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution.
We can create token using JWT::encode.

Here the sample code is :

$customClaims = ['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'bob'];
$factory = JWTFactory::customClaims($customClaims); 
$payload = $factory->make();
$token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);